# How I can scroll up and down by Keyboard In VS2008

Tags: .net, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any shortcut in VS2008 to scroll up and down by keyboard?

Although CTRL + UP and Down will move between the methods but this is not what I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard

Find the commands Edit.ScrollLineUp and Edit.ScrollLineDown.

You can see what it's set to, or set the keyboard shortcut yourself.

Comment: The shortcut is CTRL+UP for Edit.ScrollLineUp, and CTRL+Down for Edit.ScrollLineDown but it's not behaving like this!!, it's moving between methods.

Comment: Do you have a mapping for Edit.NextMethod and Edit.Previous method?  Maybe that's taking precedence?

Comment: Yes you are right, I Assign the shortcut again for the TextEditor, now it's working. Thank you...

Answer (score 2):

How about Page Up and Page Down.

Comment: thank you, but I want to scroll line by line, not for the whole page.

Comment: Use the Up and Down arrow keys then.

Comment: scroll <> moving, I want to keep the cursor on the same line and scroll up and down to see the below/upper lines.

Answer (score 0):

How about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

The <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd> key combinations *will* scroll up and down a single line.

At least in the editor modes that I use, like C#, aspx, css, html, xml. In some modes it might be taken over by the function that you describe, and in that case there is no key combination to scroll, unless you redefine the keyboard bindings.